# Autoplay function on Nivo Slider ( not wp version )

Tags: css, nivo-slider

Is there a script that I can add to nivo-slider.css that allows for control functions for auto playing , transition time etc? I would like the slideshow to just start playing on page load. Thanks

Comment: This is default behavior I think. Can you point to the implementation of the script?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the options to the slider only in JavaScript. Unfortunately you cannot add options in the CSS.

See the Nivo usage docs: [Here](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/)

To auto start:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    // Options go here
    }.start());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is old posted question but i am here giving solution for autoplay navoSlider, so it may help others.

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    manualAdvance:false,
    pauseTime:5000,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    controlNav:true,
    directionNav:true,
    directionNavHide:true,
    effect:'sliceDown',
    captionOpacity: 0.9
});
```